# Can we specify id to a ngx-datatable-column to identify it in a unique manner?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I want to assign an id attribute to a `ngx-datatable-column`. 
For example, applying an id to a div tag.

I tried  adding 'id' to `ngx-datatable` using the format `[id]="row.uniqId"` but was unsuccessful.

Is there any other way to define id to a `ngx-datatable-column`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i which want to establish a parent child connection between two component where the parent component contains a ngx-datatable and the child component contains a map with agm marker on it. when i click on the agm marker the data from the marker should transfer to the parent component and compare it with the ngx-datatable using any uniqId and then highlight that particular information in the ngx-datatable.

Comment: The information is passed to the parent component but need to assign the id attribute inside the ngx-datatable template so that it can highlight the data and that;'s not possible using id attribute? If i use div instead of ngx-datatable then the problem is resolved but i want to use ngx-datatable only.